# Confused in DataContext in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datacontext

I am beginner to WPF and MVMM architecture. VI came across many links which explains about DataContext dependence property in WPF MVMM architecture,

i.e. 
view.DataContext = new ViewModels.MainViewModel();

but they always made me confused. Although I have some basic idea about this DataContext like it is used to represent who's object we need in xaml file, but when blogs talks about tree structure inheritance of dataContext I gets confused. Can any one please help me with some very simple and clear example showing how this hierarchy of DataContext works?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/

Answer (score 2):

The `DataContext` property specifies the default source for [Data Binding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29054/WPF-Data-Binding-Part). Consider the following example:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty}" />
```

What this `Binding` says: take the value of `MyProperty` from whatever object is inside the `DataContext`, convert it to a string and put it in the `TextBox`. So if we would set the `DataContext` of the `TextBox` to be an object of the following class:

```
public class Example {
     int MyProperty { get { return 3; } }
}
```

Then, the `Text` of the `TextBox` would be set to `3`.

What does it mean that the values [Inherit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197(v=vs.110).aspx)? Consider a slightly more complex example:

```
<Window Name="MainWindow">
     <StackPanel>
          <TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty}" />
          ...etc
```

If we would have 10 or more `TextBox` elements on our screen, it would be a lot of senseless work to assign the `DataContext` to each and every TextBox. To relieve this issue, the implementors of WPF decided that setting the `DataContext` on the `MainWindow` in our case would also apply it to everything **inside** that `Window` (all children, all nested elements) until the `DataContext` property is overwritten (i.e. we set the `DataContext` of the `TextBox`, then the `TextBox` and all its children would also receive this `DataContext`).

If you want to see this behavior in action, the same applies to the `FontSize` property, try setting the `FontSize` of your `Window` to `48` and see what happens to all the text in there!

Answer (score 1):

The Datacontext property is the default source of all the binding of a View.
In MVVM, the Datacontext is used to link a ViewModel to a View.

As the Datacontext property is a dependence property, if you don't define it in a control, it will inherit from his father, etc.

Here is **an exemple of MVVM implementation** :

Parent of all ViewModel class (to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in all ViewModels) :

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Note : INotifyPropertyChanged allow your ViewModel to notify the View of a change (used for bindings).

Let's say I want a MainWindows (View) to be linked to a ViewModel :

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainViewModel mainViewModel = new MainViewModel(this);
        this.DataContext = mainViewModel;
    }
```

With for ViewModel :

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region fields

    private MainWindow mainWindow;

    private string message = "Hello world !";

    #endregion


    #region properties

    public MainWindow MainWindow
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mainWindow;
        }
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return message;
        }
        set
        {
            this.message = value; OnPropertyChanged("Message");
        }
    }

    // ...

    #endregion

    public MainViewModel(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        this.mainWindow = mainWindow;
    }
}
```

So now if I want to bind a property of MainViewModel in my View (mainwindow), i just have to have a public property in my ViewModel and to create a binding in my XAML. I won't have to specify the source as the DataContext is the default source.

So MainWindow.xaml I can add :

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Message}" />
```

Comment: This was where I was confused. 1 answer (From Antoine) shows inheritance in back-end and another (From Bas Brekelmans) shows in UI.

Again on the same page.